# how to remove cookie from request header angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

hi how can i remove cookies from request header set by

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRFToken'] = $cookies.csrftoken;
```

In header it show as

> Accept     application/json Accept-Encoding    gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language    en-US,en;q=0.5 Connection   keep-alive
>
> Cookie     JSESSIONID=F215EF9C41E8D897F103751DE8EC833C;
>   AWSELB=8BE3A51B068B8505EFF78592B3B122EBDC441C205CA70B58
>   4B154F43BD43ED2709E4137E8584EF75C8333E4C3088A0DCFCDEE1397E017F44B3036ABCFD1C213CB95EBEAF1D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cookie header is not the `X-CSRFToken` header.

these are two diffrent headers.
you could use `withCredentials`:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = false;
```

but as described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials), it will only take effect on cross-origin requests:

> setting withCredentials has no effect on same-site requests

Comment: @user2423768 did this help you? is it the correct answer? if it is please mark it as correct using 'V' sign on the left.

Comment: great :) glad to help